# AWS Toolkit for WebStorm - Debug Node.js Lambda "Cannot find module handler AWS Lambda"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, webstorm, aws-toolkit

I cannot figure out what's wrong with the following configuration of the debugger in WebStorm for the AWS Toolkit for Lambda:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an open issue on the repository: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/2835 ... it refers to a dotNET function/configuration but it's pretty similar.